# How do I install Postgresql on QNX Neutrino?

Tags: postgresql, compilation, installation, qnx-neutrino

Is there a way to get Postgresql installed on QNX neutrino?

When I try compiling the source code, starting with `./configure` it just says that QNX is not compatible operating system or something like that.

MySQL works, but I need to be able to save arrays of numbers in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is diff files for Postgresql 8.3.7 and 8.4
You can build it with this patches 
for 8.4:
http://qnx.org.ru/forum/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=2938.0;attach=91

for 8.3.7:
http://qnx.org.ru/forum/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=2938.0;attach=68

Comment: there is not allowed anonymous access - and interface is fully in Russian.

Answer (score 1):

QNX support was removed http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Remove-QNX-port-td2216118.html

You can try PostgreSQL released before Jan 2006

Comment: I tried postgre 7.3.2  using ./configure --with-template = qnx4    on qnx neutrino => checking build system type... Invalid configuration `qnx4': machine `qnx4' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh config/config.sub qnx4 failed

Comment: I can't help - I looked in src and qnx4 is supported there, this can be broken :( maybe this link will be useful for you http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql.org/pgsql-ports/2005/04/postgresql-8-0-2-and-qnx-neutrino-6-2-1/27uagcsrfwke6bxcm74zl6f2vvby